# What is the time complexity for this fibonacci implementation?

Tags: javascript, loops, time-complexity, fibonacci

Was just wondering if someone could explain what the time complexity behind this code would be. Thanks!

```
function fib(N) {
  var arr = [0, 1, 1];
  for (i = 3; i <= N; i++) {
    arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
  }
  return arr[N];
}
```

Comment: O(n). please declare all variables.

Comment: @NinaScholz Can you explain how?

Comment: The number of loop iterations (thus algorithm run time) and the number of array items are linearly associated. I.e. if you increase `N` twice as much, your code will run (***approximately***) twice as long. That's why your algorithm time complexity is O(n)

Answer (score 0):

We can split code into several parts and analyze part by part.

```
var arr = [0, 1, 1];
```

This part has `O(1)`, because it doesn't even depend on a `N`.

```
for (i = 3; i <= N; i++) {
  arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];
}
```

The more numbers we have in an array, the more time it would take to get two elements from it, however the difference is so small that we can approximately consider time of the execution of `arr[i] = arr[i - 1] + arr[i - 2];` as constant. So we must execute this code as many times as big as the `N`. Time complexity for this part is so `O(n)`.

```
return arr[N];
```

Again the difference between executing `arr[3]` or `arr[10000000]` is negligible, so the time complexity is the same every time `O(1)`.

Overall time complexity of this code is the biggest number of complexities of the parts, so it's `O(n)`.